# REGEX in Process Builder Not Working as Expected

Tags: formula, process-builder, regular-expressions

### Background

I've set up a process (in Process Builder) to update the **MobilePhone** field on the Contact object to this format: **+614xxxxxxxx** when it is entered in this format: **04xxxxxxxx**.

It has been set to run when a record is created or edited.

For troubleshooting purposes, I've set it to perform the action whenever the value in the **MobilePhone** field is in the aforementioned format - I've used a regular expression function to verify the format: `REGEX([Contact].MobilePhone,"^04[0-9]{8}$")`

[image]

Action that is performed:

[image]

### Issue

The process never updates the **MobilePhone** field if the value in the field is changed.

If the value is not changed, and the record is saved, then the process updates the value to the desired format.

Here's a GIF of the issue: https://i.imgur.com/kDRy11t.gifv

### Question

Why doesn't the process update the value in the **MobilePhone** field when it is changed?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible it isn't getting to that action in process builder? If you set the action executing criteria to "No criteria-just execute the actions!", does the mobile phone update?

Comment: Hi @Zach, I can confirm that it certainly does get to that action. Furthermore, as mentioned, the action is executed when the value in the MobilePhone field is not changed.